# Sampling conditional distribution OpenMP

Tags: c++, c++17, openmp

I have a function which draws a random sample:

```
Sample sample();
```

I have a function which checks weather a sample is valid:

```
bool is_valid(Sample s);
```

This simulates a conditional distribution. Now I want a lot of valid samples (most samples will not be valid).

So I want to parallelize this code with openMP

```
vector<Sample> valid_samples;
while(valid_samples.size() < n) {
    Sample s = sample();
    if(is_valid(s)) {
        valid_samples.push_back(s);
    }
}
```

How would I do this? Most of the OpenMP code I found were simple `for` loops where the number of iterations is determined in the beginning.

The `sample()` function has a

```
thread_local std::mt19937_64 gen([](){
    std::random_device d;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0,10000);
    return dist(d);
}());
```

as a random number generator. Is is valid and thread save if I assume that my device has a source of randomness? Are there better solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may employ OpenMP *task parallelism*. The simplest solution would be to define a task as a single sample insertion:

```
vector<Sample> valid_samples(n); // need to be resized to allow access in parallel

void insert_ith(size_t i)
{
  do {
    valid_samples[i] = sample();
  } while (!is_valid(valid_samples[i]));
}

#pragma omp parallel
{
  #pragma omp single
  {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
      #pragma omp task
      insert_ith(i);
    }
  }
}
```

Note that there might be performance issues with such single-task-single-insertion mapping. First, there would be *false sharing* involved, but likely worse, tasking management has some overhead which might be significant for very small tasks. In such a case, a remedy is simple — instead of a single insertion per tasks, insert multiple items at once, such as 100. Usually, a suitable number is a trade-off: the lower creates more tasks = more overhead, the higher may result in worse load balancing.

Comment: In my case the task are big (very unlikely to be valid), but false sharing appears to be a problem (Sample is a std::vector, so 24 Bytes). I changed it to use a local variable in the task. It's a bit difficult to benchmark because the running time depends on the seeding of the random number generators.

Comment: Could you comment on the second part of the question. How would you seed the random number generator?

Comment: Why `omp parallel` and `omp single` are not canceling out in effect?

Comment: @Unlikus Read something about OpenMP tasking. Yes, they are canceling out, but only for the generation of tasks. Then, tasks are resolved in parallel by all the threads.

Comment: @Unlikus Comment on what? How to seed? There are ways, just search Google or StackOverflow. For instance, you can incorporate thread number into seed, or create a vector of seeds for different threads and initialize them by `std::random_device`.

Comment: Read "Parallel Random Numbers: As Easy as 1, 2, 3" (https://thesalmons.org/john/random123/papers/random123sc11.pdf), their generator is implemented by many free maths libraries. (Such as Intel MKL).

Answer (score 0):

You need to take care of the critical section in your code, which is the insertion into the answer vector

something like this should work (haven't compiled because functions and types are not given)

```cpp
// create vector before parallel section because it shall be shared
vector<Sample> valid_samples(n); // set initial size to avoid reallocation
int reached_count = 0;
#pragma omp parallel shared(valid_samples, n, reached_count)
{
    while(reached_count < n) { // changed this, see comments for discussion
        Sample s = sample(); // I assume this to be thread indepent
        if(is_valid(s)) {
            #pragma omp critical
            {
                // check condition again, another thread might have already
                // reached maximum number
                if(reached_count < n) {
                    valid_samples.push_back(s);
                    reached_count = valid_samples.size();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

note that neither `sample()` nor `isvalid(s)` are inside of the critical section because I assume these functions to be far more expensive than the vector insertion or the acceptance is very rare

If that is not the case, you could work with indepent local vectors and merge in the end, but that would only gain a significant benefit if you reduce the number of synchronization in some way, like giving a fixed number of iterations (at least for a large part)

Comment: `valid_samples.size()` reading size without synchronization is _data race_.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but I accepted it, because in the worst case it runs  a single iteration (per thread) too often, which has no influence hence it is checked in the important part in the end. For many iterations, that is a neglectable difference in the number of loop iterations, which should save more time than a synchronized request

Comment: You accept data races? Even if they cause undefined behaviors in your programs?

Comment: @DanielLangr In general no, but size() should give you the current size, but that function could only give you an older size which can just be smaller in this case? Or is size counting in a std::vector writing weird numbers at some time? that Issue could be with an own int variable holding the current reached count, which you know to increase montonic

Comment: @DanielLangr regarding your answer: (I can't comment because of reputation...) single inside of parallel lets only one thread in, I don't see how that could be really parallel, (I'm not used to the task clause).

Comment: @schetefan24 std::vector.size() subtracts two pointers in many implementations, so it might not be increasing in case of a relocation and a data race. UB means UB not that it will choose between a finite set of possible outcomes.

Comment: @Unlikus good point with the pointers... realloc should occur here anyway, but I've edited the post to use a custom variable instead. (I've done this previously just in C with an own counter and plain pointers, where I have this level of control)

Comment: @schetefan24 We need to generate `n` tasks. You can do this either by a single thread (as in my case), or in parallel, but then each thread needs to generate only an exclusive subset of tasks.

Comment: It is usually not reasonable to argue about UB. But in this case, as @Unlikus wrote, when two pointers are read, if one is updated in between (as during reallocation), their subtraction is not valid then. You can perform pointer arithmetic only within the same array.

Comment: BTW, even in updated answer, reading `reached_count` for comparisons should be better accompanied with `#pragma omp atomic read`. Otherwise, there are those nasty things as local cached values and flushing.